# 403 Forbidden ao grava dados de um formulário

Tags: php, apache

Eu tenho um campo no formulário que permite tags html.
Se inserir a seguinte linha no campo e submeter o formulário, retorna o erro 403 forbidden:

```
<span style="display: none">&nbsp;</span>
```

Mas se inserir a linha com aspas simples, já não acontece o erro:

```
<span style='display: none"'>&nbsp;</span>
```

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?
Não é um erro ao trabalhar com o campo no php, porque fiz um `die("teste")` antes de qualquer `$_POST` e mesmo assim o erro é retornado na primeira opção.

**UPDATE:**

Alterei o action do formulário para um ficheiro PHP que contém apenas o código abaixo e mesmo assim retorna 403 forbidden. Alguém tem alguma idéia do que poderá ser?

```
<?php echo "teste"; ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Segundo o técnico, o erro acontece porque um bloqueio do servidor anti-spam é activado.

```
Regra 300076, antispam content.
```

Há forma de contornar isso em php, ou somente desligando a regra?

Comment: Só esclarecendo: seu objetivo é que o usuário insira conteúdo com tags html, e esse conteúdo será exibido de volta como html mesmo, né? (se for, tome cuidado com [XSS](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))

Comment: @mgibsonbr isso é um backoffice, por isso a necessidade do html, o bloqueio é que não permitimos a tag script.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente usar a função [htmlspecialchars](http://pt1.php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
<?php
  htmlspecialchars($variavel)
?>
```

Comment: Isso vai "escapar" todo o conteúdo da tag (e prevenir XSS), mas será isso que o OP quer? Em outras palavras, "permite tags html" não significa que quando os dados forem retornados do formulário eles devem vir como html, e não como texto comum (escapado)?

Comment: Então, o problema é que não chega a executar o $_POST, retorna o forbidden antes. Inseri um die("teste") antes do $_POST, pelo menos deveria imprimir a string "teste" em tela, o que não conteceu.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sou um entusiasta em php, mas tenho quase certeza que quando o PHP lê isso ele transforma numa string:

```
"<span style="display: none">&nbsp;</span>"
```

E por isso que o style deve estar com seus valores em aspas simples para ser convertido:

```
"<span style='display: none'>&nbsp;</span>"
```

Como nosso caro amigo @rafaelcpalmeida citou você pode utilizar a função [htmlspecialchars](http://pt1.php.net/htmlspecialchars).

Comment: De fato, se essa string estiver **no código-fonte** o PHP interpretaria dessa forma. Mas pelo que eu entendi isso são dados de um campo no formulário, submetidos pelo usuário - estarão em uma variável, não no fonte PHP.

Comment: E se no caso ele der um echo nessa string ela não seria convertida e inserida no html?

Comment: Inserida no html, sim, mas inserida no PHP não... [Exemplo](https://ideone.com/9npuuA)

Comment: Sim, no html mesmo.

Comment: Então, o problema é que não chega a executar o $_POST, retorna o forbidden antes. Inseri um die("teste") antes do $_POST, pelo menos deveria imprimir a string "teste" em tela, o que não conteceu.

Answer (score 0):

De qualquer forma, sua segunda opção com **aspas simples** está incorreta:

```
<span style='display: none"'>&nbsp;</span>
```

Tem uma `"` passando ai. O correto seria:

```
<span style='display: none'>&nbsp;</span>
```

---

Talvez o problema seja no momento de salvar estes dados no database. Se for e você utilizar **MySQL**, use a função `mysql_real_escape_string($html_aqui)`.

---

Fiz um pequeno teste/exemplo aqui, e tudo funcionou corretamente. Não creio que o problema seja apenas isso.

> Lembrando que eu utilizei o método POST

#### formulário.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Form tag</title>
</head>
<body>

  <?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { ?>
    <strong>$_POST:</strong>
    <pre><?php echo var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>
  <?php } ?>

  <form action="formtag.php" method='POST'>
    <input type="text" name='tag'>
    <button type="submit">Go!</button>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

#### resposta (html)

```
$_POST:
array(1) {
  ["tag"]=>
  string(41) ""
}
```

#### resposta (source)

```
array(1) {
  ["tag"]=>
  string(41) "<span style="display: none">&nbsp;</span>"
}
```

Poderia postar o código completo do seu formulário?

Comment: A aspa dupla foi só um erro na hora de digitar, no fonte está correto. Também acho que o problema é outro porque não chega a executar o php, retorna o forbidden antes. Procurei saber e existe um software a correr no servidor que evita ataques XSS, talvez seja isso.

Comment: Jà procurou debugar o código? Pra ver se isso não ocorre em X etapa, ou se ja é inicialmente na requisição?

Comment: Sim, inclusive alterei o "action" do form, para um ficheiro PHP que contém apenas "echo 'teste';", mesmo assim ainda continua a aparecer 403 Forbidden. Poderá ser algum bloqueio no servidor?